# How to get single unique permutation entry from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, combinations, permutation

I have this list after permutation:

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4], 2))
```

Here's the output :

[**(1, 2)**, (1, 3), (1, 4),
 **(2, 1)**, (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]

In that list we can find replicated elements like (1,2) - (2,1) and (1,3) - (3,1) and so ..

What I want is to get only one replicate element from this list, output list like:

```
[(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(2, 3),(2, 4),(3, 4)]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the combinations of the list, and not the permutations. For that there is [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function in Python:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list(combinations(l, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

As per the [document](https://betterexplained.com/articles/easy-permutations-and-combinations/):

> - **Permutations** are for lists **(order matters)**
> - **Combinations** are for groups **(order doesn’t matter)**.